# This name error keeps popping up despite me importing the relevant library- // cur = conn.cursor()// conn is not defined?

Tags: python-3.x, database, psycopg2, nameerror, pgadmin-4

```
cur = conn.cursor() conn is not defined
```

I have imported psycopg2 and therefore, the conn module should be recognised.
Below is my script if needs be.

```
# Small script to show PostgreSQL and Pyscopg together
import psycopg2

connection_to_db = psycopg2.connect("dbname='XYZ' user='XYZ' host='localhost' password='XYZ'")

try:
   if connection_to_db:
    print("Logged in")
except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database")


cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT ** FROM weather ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conn is not defined here. Either change `connection_to_db` to be `conn` or define it as a context manager. A benefit of context managers is that you don't have to close the connection manually

```
with psycopg2.connect("dbname='XYZ' user='XYZ' host='localhost' password='XYZ'") as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("SELECT ** FROM weather ")
```

Comment: Thnx- just as simple error overlooked